# Plotting the difference between two parallel measurements on a different time base in MatPlotLib

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have run an experiment where I am measuring the same parameter with two devices: One is under test, and the other is calibrated. They both generate a csv that I am importing into two separate dataframes in pandas of the form:

TimeStamp,MeasurementValue

The device under test and the calibrated measurement device have different sampling rates, so the measurement TimeStamps of the two csv files don't perfectly line up. There will also be multiple data points on the device under test for every data point on the calibrated measurement device.

DF1 (EUT)
TimeStamp,MeasurementValue

1602531853.36496,400

1602531853.56531,390

DF2
TimeStamp,MeasurementValue

1602531853.40507,415

1602531853.80492,405

I would like to plot the difference between the two curves as efficiently as possible because there are tens of thousands of data points.

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) article on how to post a good reproducible question. we need a copy/paste-able sample DataFrame and a sample of what you want your output to look like(if possible)

Comment: Thanks! I think I actually ended up answering my own question in this case using merge and then fillna. But I'll follow this guide on my next question.